# Qt 5.2 unexpected external symbol

Tags: windows, qt, qt5, qmainwindow, qxmpp

I made project on linux with qt 4.7 and qxmpp 0.7.6, all works good
I installed Qt 5.2 on windows, compiled qxmpp and installed it, it has finished successfully and is in
`C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\5.2.0\msvc2010\include\qxmpp` dir, seems all went good
I copied project from linux, changed includepath for qxmpp so it suits windows now and run qmake, no problem
but when I wanted to run it i got 122 errors all look like this:

`mainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol “__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall QXmppCallManager::~QXmppCallManager(void)” (__imp_??1QXmppCallManager@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function “public: virtual __thiscall MainWindow::~MainWindow(void)” (??1MainWindow@@UAE@XZ)`

all errors are for qxmpp classes

here is my .pro file

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\5.2.0\msvc2010\include\qxmpp"
 
QT       += core gui network xml multimedia widgets
 
TARGET = IM-client
TEMPLATE = app
 
 
SOURCES += main.cpp\
#more sources etc
```

any idea what can be this caused by?

Comment: What about the libraries (aka DLLs) - for windoze, you might need to add additional directories for LIBS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not linking your project with the qxmpp library. I don't have any idea how it can compile even under linux without having the `LIBS += ...` line present.

My bet is: you've cut out the `LIBS` line, and that line is left from the Linux compilation, and doesn't make sense on Windows. You need to adjust it just like you did for INCLUDEPATH.

You may also want to have separate settings for both platforms, so that you don't have to continuously tweak the project file:

```
win32 {
  INCLUDEPATH += ...
  LIBS += ...
}
unix {
  INCLUDEPATH += ...
  LIBS += ...
}
```

Comment: thank you I must've deleted this part when editing .pro file somehow without noticing.

Comment: @Ruli: Use version control. Commit often. You won't ever have such a problem again.